# How to convert light activated switch

Tags: switches, schematics

[image]

Can anyone teach me how to convert a light activated switch into  dark activated switch vice versa.

Comment: Simply flip the position of the R1 with LDR.

Comment: Your schematic shows a mains earth connection to the mains supply. This should not be done. You must have a floating 12 V supply and you must treat the whole circuit as live.

Comment: What do you mean by "a floating 12 V supply" sir? Sorry im a bit new in this field

Comment: A floating power supply is one whose output has no internal connection to the mains or earth. Your schematic shows an earth connection connected to one of the mains wires. This is a "bad thing". When you're new in this field you should work on something other than live circuits.

Comment: To elaborate, the identified conductor(neutral/return) of your 230VAC mains connection must not be grounded downstream of the nearest circuit breaker.  It is connected to ground in the panel, and it is important it not connect to ground after it leaves the panel on a branch circuit because the intent of an identified conductor is to provide a "grounded" wire that is fully separate from the ground used for safety.  Current travelling on the actual line voltage ground wire is fault current and undesired in almost every case.

Comment: There are actually different symbols for different types of "ground", but be aware that ground as used in the colloquial or electronics engineering context is often a bit less specific than "ground" in a line voltage scenario.

Comment: Can you give me a circuit diagram of a light activated switch?