# How to convert light activated switch into dark activated switch

Tags: switches, schematics

Can anyoe teach me how to convert this into light activated switch 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6lZH.jpg)

Comment: Can anyone guide me how to convert this dark activated switch into light activated switch. Thank you

Comment: See duplicate : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/414449/152903

Answer (score 0):

Switch the LDR and 4.7K resistor.

Comment: Is that all? Thank you sir :)

Comment: Sir 4.7k or 47k? And which one?

Comment: 4k7 means a 4.7k resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 6 is floating.. connect pin 6 with pin 2. (By doing so you are connecting inverting and non-inverting comparator together.

and change the 4.7K resistor with 1M ohm variable resistor .

Slowly change the resistance and adjust the sensitivity based on your ambient light.